# Что показывает BenchmarkDotNet?

Tags: c#, .net, list, linked-list, benchmark

Можете объяснить, что означает каждый столбец в результатах работы BenchmarkDotNet? А также что означает Warninig. Скриншот прикрепляю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Там обычно снизу пишет "Legend" или что-то такое, где есть описание каждого столбца.

Comment: Вставьте текстовую информацию текстом